# Would a religion at the intersection of all Abrahamic religions conflict with the Qur'an or Sunnah?

Tags: other-religions, prophet-ibrahim

Is there any research in Quran about the intersection of all Abrahamic religions? Something like "joint protocol monotheists"?

Is there any commands in Qur'an or hadith from Prophet Muhammad (A.S) which would make this impossible? can we permit to Codification for 7 billion people that convert to that then convert to Islam. Can we hope that everyone in the world can understand all the rules of Islam in A stage?

> All of us in any religion decide to be good followers of Ibrahim
>   (PBUH), which is a point of commonality.If all monotheists can agree
>   on common points and be union together, such as the unification of
>   Europe would have many positive effects, Profits and bonuses.

Is the religion of Islam itself could be a mediator.

> Is Islam itself can be gradually accepted?Do we expect a new converted
>   Muslims can be like the first Muslims who embraced Islam? (At the time
>   of the Prophet and the first time the advent of Islam)

It was lower when the commands of Islam. The basic principles of faith in God and basic commands there?

> once upon a time there was lower commands in Islam. only exist The basic principles of faith. Can we define a middle stage for new converted to islam.  God and basic commands there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about the topic of Islam.

Comment: the real Islam is that to close us and last other people with other religions to unfiy

Comment: I changed the question a bit with the aim of getting it into "on topic" territory.

Comment: I heard about some "universalists" who try to mix all religions, including non-monotheist ones. They contradict by picking only the parts of the quran they prefer (usually the non-violent ones), which makes some muslims nervous.

Comment: we silent so others working. we should try to make movement to closer people into truth and Alliance and Unity and Show the way clear for all

Comment: "Behold, the only [true] religion in the sight of God is [man's] self-surrender unto Him" (Al-i-Imran 19). take a look at the Tafaseer under this verse of Quran. I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRpRpMKeFzw) Arabic talk from Al-Haydari may be useful for you too.

Comment: Based on this verse of Quran there is not any conflict between Abrahamic religions in the principles and the difference is in some practical provisions of each branch due to its temporal conditions. hope this help!

Comment: This is basically a what if question and attracts opinion based answers.